# C# send raw print on XP

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

As stated in the title i use the helper from this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091 to send raw data to a printer.

Every thing gone right if i run on my machine (windows 7 with HP LaserJet 3050 PCL5 as target printer) and the PDF is produced as expected.

If i run the same code form a PC that use XP and an Epson priner nothing happened (no error, but the print is not produced).

Anyone can explain why of this behaviour ? is an XP issue or may be a problem related to the printer ?

Comment: What is the format of raw data : simple Ascii text, Postcript, PDL, ... ?

Comment: it is a stream (passed as byte array) contining the PDF file (as is stored on filesystem)

Comment: As your HP LaserJet printer is a multifunction printer, it embeds Scan to Pdf and Pdf to Print functionalities. This is probably not the case of your Epson printer. Therefore, no simple solution :(

Comment: @Graffito yes you are right the problem can be solved calling Adobe (for pdf to printer translation) if printer does not provide pdf support.